# Парсинг картинок через Jsoup

Tags: android, парсер, jsoup

Пытаюсь написать приложение которое парсит заголовки с картинками. Не понимаю что нужно добавить в атрибуты items.setImage_id();

```
private void getWeb()
{
    try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect("URL").get();
        Elements tables = doc.getElementsByClass("name class");
        Elements img = doc.getElementsByClass("o-news-article__media");
        Element news_img = img.get(0);
        Elements elements_from_news = news_img.children();
        Element image = elements_from_news.get(0);
        for (int i = 0; i < img.size(); i++){
            ListItemClass items = new ListItemClass();
            items.setImage_id();
            arrayList.add(items);
        }
        Element our_table = tables.get(0);
        Elements elements_from_table = our_table.children();
        Element article = elements_from_table.get(0);
        Elements article_element = article.children();
        Log.d("MyLog", "img size : " +img);
        for (int i = 0; i < our_table.childrenSize();i++)
        {
            ListItemClass items = new ListItemClass();
            items.setData_1(our_table.children().get(i).child(0).text());
            arrayList.add(items);
        }
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: вопрос не очень понятен, уточните пожалуйста где именно и с чем у вас возникла проблема, какое поведение вы хотите получить

Comment: items.setImage_id(); в скобках не знаю какие прописать параметры что бы спарсить картинку в ImageView.
пример items.setData_1(our_table.children().get(i).child(0).text()); выводит текст в TextView.

Comment: зажмите ctrl и наведите на этот метод, вас перебросит в документацию, где будет написано что он ждёт на вход

Answer (score 0, accepted):

пришлось изменить код как в этом примере https://github.com/gifffert/ParseSiteData

```
String url = "https://www.elitedangerous.com/de-DE/neues/galnet";

                    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

                    Elements data = doc.select("article.o-news-article");
                    int size = data.size();
                    Log.d("doc", "doc: " + doc);
                    Log.d("data", "data: " + data);
                    Log.d("size", "" + size);
                    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                        String imgUrl = data.select("div.o-news-article__media")
                                .select("img")
                                .eq(i)
                                .attr("src");

                        String title = data.select("div.o-news-article__info")
                                .select("h1")
                                .eq(i)
                                .text();

                        String detailUrl = data.select("a")
                                //.select("a")
                                .eq(i)
                                .attr("href");

                        parseItems.add(new ParseItem(imgUrl, title, detailUrl));
                        Log.d("items", "img: " + imgUrl + " . title: " + title + "Url" + detailUrl);
                    }
                    break;
```